# How to do this Poisson bracket proof

Tags: dynamical-systems, physics, poisson-geometry

[image]

[image]

For the proof of the above equation, I understand the first step which has been obtained from the definition but in the second step I don't understand why they are summing over $j$ first (shouldn't the summation still be in $i$?) and then multiplying by $i$ in the second line the terms in the bracket. Also don't understand how they got each of the terms in the second line from the terms in the first line. Also, how did they get for the second term in the second line, $g(\partial f/\partial q_j)(\partial h/\partial p_j)$? when the other three terms have $q$'s and $p$'s in terms of $i$ so shouldn't the second term also have $q_i$ and $p_i$ in the denominator instead of $j$'s?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The second step looks to contain a typo in which they erroneously duplicated the $g (\partial f/\partial p_i) (\partial h/\partial q_i)$ term.

Comment: The other terms you mentioned can be obtained with the usual Leibnitz rule of partial derivatives, the last term according to the same rule should be multiplied by h and not by g, and of course the partial derivatives should then act on the g and not again on the h. Then you can factor the g and the h and apply back the definition of the poisson bracket.

Comment: Considering your other question about Poisson brackets, it seems that you should try to find a better book (with less typos)...